# How do I display a property from a simple object using ngrx redux and angular2

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm using angular2 2.0.0-beta.2 with ngrx store https://github.com/ngrx/store and implemented a simple app using a modified version of the "counter" example on the ngrx/store github page.

In my app, I have a "user" object with two buttons for **login** and **logout**. I also have the corresponding reducer functions **login** and **logout** where I either return the state with an object that includes a name property or with an empty object...

```
export const user: Reducer<any> = (state: any = {}, action: Action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN:
            return {name: 'jdoe'};

        case LOGOUT:
            return {};

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**This doesn't update:**

```
<h2>User Name = {{ user.name | async }}</h2>
```

...It remains blank when I click the login button, but when piped through the 'json' pipe, I see that indeed the object has changed...

**This does update**

```
{{ user | async | json }}
```

...which outputs **{ "name": "jdoe" }** but obviously that does me no good. Using simply {{ user.name | async }} doesn't work and remains blank.

the template:

```
<div>
    <h2>User Name = {{ user.name | async }}</h2>
    <button (click)="login()">login</button><button (click)="logout()">logout</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
      {{ user | async | json }}
</div>
```

Here's the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/cPubI9upph344qrOqtj8?p=preview

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Syntax looks like `(user | async).name` - see http://plnkr.co/edit/OVHh9lHvTU4sKrCbrLqq?p=preview

Comment: Awesome, that did the job! I wasn't familiar with that syntax, thanks!

Comment: How would I go if I would need to access user.name outside the template, for example in a function?

Comment: Wow, this should be displayed prominently in the docs somewhere -- spent a couple of hours figuring out why my properties would not display to the screen.  Thank you!  Finally solved this via this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
    <div *ngIf="user | async as userdata">
     {{userdata.name}}
     {{userdata.birthday}}
     ...
    </div>
```